# Javascript/AJAX Asynchronous Loading Spinners

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spinner, loading

I am trying to make a basic enough page that allows the user to execute a php script by clicking a button. Each button will have a loading spinner popup on clicking.

My problem is, on clicking one button and then clicking another, both spinners close at the exact same time even though the second may still be processing.

Does anyone know how to make these spinners truly asynchronous ? Thanks so much in advance, its killing me.

JS:

```
function test(element){
    var append = "#";
    var test = append.concat(element);

    document.getElementById(element).style.visibility='visible';

            $.ajax({url:"test.php",success:function(result){
                    hide(element);
            }

            });
         };

    function hide(element){
        document.getElementById(element).style.visibility='hidden';
    };


</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <?
    $index = 0;
$myArray = array ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
for($index = 0; $index < 5; $index++){?>

    <button   onclick="test('<?echo $myArray [$index];?>')">Start</button>

<img id="<?echo $myArray [$index];?>" src="images/loader.gif"        
     style="visibility:hidden"/>
    <br><br>

    <?}?>

   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a counter. Each time you show the loading indicator, add one to the counter and each time you want to hide it, subtract one. Then monitor the counter and whenever it is above zero show the loading indicator and when at zero hide it.  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I get your drift alright, I shall report back, suggestions welcome in the meantime anyone.

Comment: Just checking you know I meant there would be like 5 loading spinners ? Not just one

Comment: You want five loading indicators or just one?

Comment: More than one, the code posted would create five, the application would require multiple indicators. Thanks a lot for any ideas you have.

Comment: If you want five separate loading indicators, I don't see any blatant errors in your code.  You may want to inspect your HTML page after it is rendered by PHP and make sure you don't have any PHP errors such as mis-matched quotes.

Comment: True, the code works but the problem is: each ajax call to the php page is gonna take about 5 seconds when fully developed, if multiple buttons are pressed they will all close at the same time as the first button instead of five seconds respectively. It's sort of tricky ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following (untested) code might do the trick and it neatly means you can avoid worrying about the spinner at all in ajax requests:

```
var spinningAjax = (function() { // use of the closure created by an immediate function gives us the scope to create a persistant counter variable
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter === 0) {
            showSpinner(false);
        }
    });
    return function(settings) {
        counter++;
        showSpinner(true);
        $.ajax(settings);
    }
})();

var showSpinner(bool) {
    // I'll leave this up to you as it looks like your posted html / js is for example purposes rather than replicating your actual site
};
```

**EDIT:** Ok, having seen the comments to another answer, I realise this doesn't quite solve the situation you're in. I'll have a think and see if I can do better

**EDIT2:** I think this (still untested, unfortunately) code may be what you require. Please let me know in the comments if you have any issues.

```
var spinningAjax = (function() {  // closure of immediate function lets us create a persistant array of the counters for each spinner
    var counter = [];  // an array to hold the counters for each spinner
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) { // called whenever any ajax request is completed
        if (typeof settings.ajaxGroup !== 'undefined') { // only update the counters if an ajaxGroup has been provided
            counter[settings.ajaxGroup]--;
            if (counter[settings.ajaxGroup] === 0) {
                showSpinner(false, settings.ajaxGroup); // hide spinner when all requests connected with the spinner have been completed
            }
        }
    });
    return function(settings) { // this is the function actually assigned to the variable spinningAjax as a result of the immediate function
        counter[settings.ajaxGroup] = counter[settings.ajaxGroup] ? counter[settings.ajaxGroup]+1 : 1; // can't just use the ++ operator as this property might not be defined yet
        showSpinner(true, settings.ajaxGroup);
        $.ajax(settings);
    }
})();

var showSpinner(bool, spinnerIdentifier) {
    // I'll leave this up to you as it looks like your posted html / js is for example purposes rather than replicating your actual site
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time either way